# How do I Mocks props method in the react test?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to test code when tab featured is enabled. The code which does that is below:

```
const isTabEnabled = ():boolean => {
    return interPluginContext.isValid();
};
```

and in my render method

```
{isTabEnabled()
              ? createdTabbedContent()
              : createContent()}
```

The test looks like below

```
interface Props {
  interPluginContext: InterPluginContext;
  srType: SupportType;
  errorMessage: undefined;
}

it("check title when tab mode is enabled", () => {
    const mockContextFunc = jest.spyOn(context, "usePluginContext");
    mockContextFunc.mockImplementation(() => {return true;});
});
```

The test always returns false How do I mock the interPluginContext.isValid() in my test? When I tried to mock like below

```
const mockContextFunc = jest.spyOn(context, "usePluginContext");
mockContextFunc.mockImplementation(() => {return true;});
```

I get an error:

```
Argument of type '() => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => InterPluginContext'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'InterPluginContext'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the test like below

```
const props = {
  interPluginContext: {
    isValid: () => true,
  } as InterPluginContext,
};
```

and it worked.